# Android CursorLoader vs AsyncQueryHandler?

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I have seen how to implement both a CursorLoader and a AsyncQueryHandler. If I wanted to use this for an Android 2.2 application for a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter, which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I had someone [recommend me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842412/confused-about-cursorloaders-and-using-them-with-a-custom-sqliteopenhelper) a very nice library that made working with CursorLoaders quite painless. To be fair, that was mostly for use with a list and using a ResourceCursorAdapter, but it worked well for me. I'd recommend using a CursorLoader and this library.